# A linear transformation such that $T(AB)=T(BA)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, trace

The question goes as follows:
Let $V$ be a vector space and let $T: M_{2 \times 2} (R) —> V$ such that $T(AB)=T(BA)$ for all $A, B \in M_{2 \times 2}$.  Show that $T(A) = 1/2(trA)T(I2)$ for all $A \in M_{2 \times 2}$.

I have no clue how to approach this. I’ve tried everything but I keep going in circles. Please help me.

Comment: There isn’t really enough back ground to know what a helpful answer would be. Is T linear?

Comment: Yes it’s linear!

Comment: Every matrix $C$ with trace zero [is a commutator](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/MathH110/trace0.pdf), namely it is of the form $AB-BA$, and therefore $T(C)=0$. Then, for an arbitrary matrix $A$ you have $T(A)=T(A-\frac{1}{2}tr(A)I_2+\frac{1}{2}tr(A)I_2)=T(A-\frac{1}{2}tr(A)I_2)+T(\frac{1}{2}tr(A)I_2)$. Since $A-\frac{1}{2}tr(A)I_2$ has trace $0$ it is a commutator and therefore $T(A-\frac{1}{2}tr(A)I_2)=0$. Then $T(A)=\frac{1}{2}tr(A)T(I_2)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there a way to find the matrices A and B?

Comment: Yes, the proof in the link tells you how combining lemma 1 and 2. You could work out explicit formulas for the case of $2\times 2$ matrices. Separate two cases: Matrices $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&-a\end{pmatrix}$ in which $a=0$ and matrices in which $a\neq0$. In the first Lemma 1 already gives you explicit formulas. In the second case,first compute the matrix $B$ as in Lemma 2, and then using lemma 1 as in the third paragraph of the proof of Theorem 3, tells you how to the the corresponding commutator.

Answer (score 2):

First,we know that $T$ is a linear transfromation.
Then,we just need to considering a basis of $M_{2\times 2}$.There we choose a basis as following.
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}1 & 0\\0& 0\\\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{c}0 & 1\\0& 0\\\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{c}0 & 0\\1& 0\\\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{c}0 & 0\\0& 1\\\end{array}\right)$$
We observe that 
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}0 & 1\\0& 0\\\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}0 & 1\\0& 0\\\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}0 & 0\\0& 1\\\end{array}\right)$$ 
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}0 & 0\\0& 0\\\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}0 & 0\\0& 1\\\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}0 & 1\\0& 0\\\end{array}\right)$$
so,$T\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}0 & 1\\0& 0\\\end{array}\right)\right)=T\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}0 & 0\\0& 0\\\end{array}\right)\right)=\mathbf{0}$.
similarly,$T\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}0 & 0\\1& 0\\\end{array}\right)\right)=T\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}0 & 0\\0& 0\\\end{array}\right)\right)=\mathbf{0}$.
One can observe that 
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}1 & 0\\0& 0\\\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}0 & 1\\1& 0\\\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}0 & 1\\1& 0\\\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}0 & 0\\0& 1\\\end{array}\right)$$
Hence,$$T\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}1 & 0\\0& 0\\\end{array}\right)\right)=T\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}0 & 0\\0& 1\\\end{array}\right)\right)=\dfrac{1}{2}T\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}1 & 0\\0& 1\\\end{array}\right)\right)$$.

we conclude that $$T(A)=T\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}a & b\\c& d\\\end{array}\right)\right)=aT\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}1 & 0\\0& 0\\\end{array}\right)\right)+bT\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}0 & 1\\0& 0\\\end{array}\right)\right)+cT\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}0 & 0\\1& 0\\\end{array}\right)\right)+dT\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}0 & 0\\0& 1\\\end{array}\right)\right).$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{2}tr(A)T(I_2)$$
The proof is completed.

Comment: the proof does not need to quote any conclusion,but it may be tedious.

Comment: I think that is fine. It is an argument easy to follow, using the ideas that students starting in linear algebra should be familiar with.

Comment: I can't quite see why $$\left(\begin{array}{c}1 & 0\\0& 0\\\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}0 & 1\\1& 0\\\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}0 & 1\\1& 0\\\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}0 & 0\\0& 1\\\end{array}\right)$$
implies $$T\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}1 & 0\\0& 0\\\end{array}\right)\right)=T\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}0 & 0\\0& 1\\\end{array}\right)\right)$$, could you provide clarification, thank you.

Comment: $T(AC)=T(CB) \Rightarrow T(ACC^{-1})=T(C^{-1}AC)=T(C^{-1}CB)=T(B).$

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $X\in M_2(\mathbb R)$ has a zero trace, it must lie inside the linear span of $\{AB-BA:A,B\in M_2(\mathbb R)\}$:
\begin{aligned}
X=\pmatrix{a&b\\ c&-a}
&=\frac12\left[\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}\pmatrix{0&-a\\ a&0}-\pmatrix{0&-a\\ a&0}\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}\right]\\
&+\frac12\left[\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&-1}\pmatrix{0&b\\ -c&0}-\pmatrix{0&b\\ -c&0}\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&-1}\right].
\end{aligned}
(In fact, it can be shown that the set $\{AB-BA:A,B\in M_2(\mathbb R)\}$ itself --- without linear span --- is precisely the set of all real $2\times2$ traceless matrices, but this is unimportant here.) Therefore $T(X)=0$ whenever $\operatorname{tr}(X)=0$. Now, for every matrix $A\in M_2(\mathbb R)$, we can split it into the sum of a traceless component $X=A-\frac12\operatorname{tr}(A)I_2$ and a trace component $Y=\frac12\operatorname{tr}(A)I_2$. It follows that
$$
T(A)=T(X)+T(Y)=T(Y)=\frac12\operatorname{tr}(A)T(I_2).
$$